# dynamic array allocation and printing the elements

Tags: c

```
t=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

do
{
    printf("enter the element");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    *a=n;
    printf("%d",a[i]);
    a=(int*)realloc(t,sizeof(int));
    i++;
}   while(i<4);
```

I am not able to print the elements of dynamic array after my first element.

Comment: This does not seem like C# to me. Are you sure this isn't C/C++?

Comment: In your code, `a[]` is never bigger than one `int`. Calling`a[0]` may be fine (depending how you allocated it...), but calling `a[1]` is dangerous as you try to access a memory that is not allocated...This may trigger a segmentation fault. Try `a=(int*)realloc(t,sizeof(int)*(i+1));`

Answer (score 1):

`a=(int*)realloc(t,sizeof(int));` You are trying to reallocate dynamic memory to just one integer size every time in the loop. Instead take a local variable `count` for number of elements to read in as,

```
int count = 0; 
do
{
   printf("enter the element");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   printf("%d",a[i]);
   a = (int*)realloc(t, count * sizeof(int));
   a[count - 1] = n;
   i++;
} while(i<4);
free(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues:

```
t=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Don't cast the result of `malloc` (in C); it's unnecessary, and in older compilers it can suppress a useful diagnostic.  Similarly, use the size of the actual object, rather than the type; that will save you some maintenance headaches:

```
t = malloc( sizeof *t );
```

Cleaner, easier to read, and not prone to issues if you decide to change the type of `t`.  Although, given your code below, I think you meant for `t` to be `a`.

```
do
{
    printf("enter the element");
```

Standard output is *line buffered*, meaning output is held until either the buffer is full or you send a newline character.  To make sure your output shows up immediately, use `fflush`:

```
    fflush( stdout );
    scanf("%d",&n);
    *a=n;
```

Has `a` been properly initialized to point anywhere yet?  `t` and `a` are different objects, so assigning to `t` doesn't mean `a` is pointing anywhere meaningfule.  Secondly, `*a` is equivalent to `a[0]`; are you sure you don't want to write

```
    a[i] = n;
```

especially given the line:

```
    printf("%d",a[i]);
    a=(int*)realloc(t,sizeof(int));
```

Same as above; drop the cast, use the size of the object itself:

```
    a = realloc( t, sizeof *a );
```

**BUT**, this has problems too.  You're not actually *extending* your array; you keep allocating the exact same amount of space as when you started.  And you keep using the same starting pointer, which may be different from your most recent result.

```
    i++;
}   while(i<4);
```

Here's what I *think* you're tryihng to do:

```
a = malloc( sizeof *a );
i = 0;

do
{
  printf( "enter a the element: " );
  fflush( stdout );
  scanf( "%d", &a[i] );
  printf( "%d\n", &a[i] );
  int *tmp = realloc( a, sizeof *a * (i+2) );   // +2 since i starts from 0
  if ( tmp )                                    // the array by one element
    a = tmp;                                    // only assign if realloc succeeded
} while ( ++i < 4 );
```

As a rule, extending an array one element at a time is expensive and inefficient; normally, you'd extend the array by some number of elements at once, reducing the number of times you have to call `realloc`:

```
size_t count = START_SIZE;
T *a = malloc( sizeof *a * count );
...
if ( idx == count )
{
  T *tmp = realloc( a, sizeof *a * (2 * count) );  // double the size of the buffer
  if ( tmp )                                       // each time we run up against
  {                                                // the limit.
    a = tmp;
    count *= 2;
  }
}
a[idx] = new_value;
```